# This page crashed. when I use named docusaurus-search-local,Then I run npm run start,It's been error，The page becomes like this

Tags: docusaurus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr8UG.png)

when I use named  docusaurus-search-local,Then I run npm run start,It's been error，The page becomes like this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can click the picture link above. This is a screenshot of my page